# Get method does not return any response in RestAssured Java in eclipse

Tags: rest-assured

Can someone please help me here, below is the code:

```
package student.profile.picture;


import io.restassured.RestAssured;

import io.restassured.response.Response;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;


import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class GetProfilePicture {

    @Test
     void Fetch() 


    {
        RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:5100"; // giving base URI
        Response res=given().
        header("tenantId","Augusta-PT").
        when().
        get("/ProfilePicture").
        then().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response();
        String responsestring=res.asString();
        System.out.println(responsestring);
        /*JsonPath js = new JsonPath(responsestring);
        String FileContentType = js.get("fileContentType");
        String ExpectedFilecontenttype = "image/png";
        System.out.println(FileContentType);
        Assert.assertEquals(FileContentType, ExpectedFilecontenttype); */


    }

}
```

It does not show any error, it is a simple get method to show response, nothing shows up in console.

Any help please?

Comment: Fix formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to break up your statement in two parts,

First, get the response,

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:5100";
Response res = given()
  .header("tenantId","Augusta-PT")
  .when()
  .get("/ProfilePicture");
```

And second part to assert,

```
res.then()
  .assertThat()
  .statusCode(200);
System.out.println(res.asString());
```

This will solve your issue and you should be able to get the response in console.